# Simple login/security for an Azure asp.net site (without db)?

Tags: asp.net, security, azure, c#-3.0

I have a demo site that requires a simple login security similar to basic authenication. When a url is entered, a login popups and prompts for username/password. Unfortunately, basic authentication is not available in Azure. Something that requires very little code and I can just store my username/password in the webconfig.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Outside of creating a simple javascript login, I didn't find anything similar to basic authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, basic authentication is always customizable, it doesn't necessary mean that Windows accounts are used. You can pretty much plug your custom membership provider here, as I've blogged once:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/11/basic-authentication-module-with-custom.html

Second, using forms authentication with a custom membership provider is always a simple option. In your provider, passwords can be read from anywhere.